# CSS animation not behaving as expected

Tags: html, css, css-animations, css-transitions

### Problem

I've made a simple css animation, but it's not behaving as I expect it.
The idea is for the animation to draw a straight line (from top downwards) , and the disappear (also from the top downwards).

The start of the line moves down a bit, as the animation starts, then up again to stay at set position (same goes for the bottom at the end of the animation).

### Question

How do I get the start of the line to stay at one position instead of 'bouncing' down and up?

#### Expected behavior

[image]

#### Actual behavior

[image]

#### Code

```css
.lineWrapper {
  width: 1px;
  height: 300px;
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
}

.lineWrapper .line {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #000;
  animation: scrollLine 5s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes scrollLine {
  0% {
    transform: scaleY(0);
  }
  10% {
    transform: scaleY(0);
    transform-origin: top;
  }
  30% {
    transform: scaleY(1);
  }
  70% {
    transform: scaleY(1);
  }
  90% {
    transform: scaleY(0);
    transform-origin: bottom;
  }
  100% {
    transform: scaleY(0);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="lineWrapper">
  <div class="line"></div>
</div>
```

#### Codepen

https://codepen.io/strazan/pen/RwPYgjq

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default `transform-origin` is center so if you omit it in the initial and last state it will be set to center. You need to also have an instant change of the `transform-origin` in the middle:

```css
.lineWrapper {
  width: 1px;
  height: 300px;
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
}

.line {
  height: 100%;
  background: #000;
  animation: scrollLine 5s infinite;
}

@keyframes scrollLine {
  0%,10% {
    transform: scaleY(0);
    transform-origin: top;
  }
  49.9% {
    transform: scaleY(1);
    transform-origin: top;
  }
  50% {
    transform: scaleY(1);
    transform-origin: bottom;
  }
  90%,100% {
    transform: scaleY(0);
    transform-origin: bottom;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="lineWrapper">
  <div class="line"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Aaah! I understand now! Thank you very much! :D

Answer (score 0):

I have made similar CSS animation with some different code lines.

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  background: black;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.line-wrapper {
  height: 800px;
  width: 8px;
  background: tranparent;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  animation: down 2s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes down {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(0px);
  }

  15% {
    transform: translateY(0px);
  }

  30% {
    transform: translateY(0px);
  }

  60% {
    transform: translateY(90px);
  }

  90% {
    transform: translateY(115px);
  }

  100% {
    transform: translateY(115px);
  }
}

.line {
  height: 8px;
  width: 4px;
  background: Gray;
  animation: scrollLine 2s ease-in-out infinite;
}

@keyframes scrollLine {
  100% {
    height: 800px;
  }
}

.eraser {
  height: 0px;
  width: 4px;
  background: black;
  animation: rmv 2s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes rmv {
  55% {
    height: 0px;
  }

  100% {
    height: 800px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="line-wrapper">
  <div class="line">
    <div class="eraser"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```